# How to forward action processing to a second action in Laravel Controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

I have two similar user profiles, and they share pretty much the same view structure and information. However, a "special user profile" would display an additional block, and require a different URL - say, `/user/igor` and  `/special-user/igor`.

What's the best approach to handle this?

In other frameworks I would have pseudocode similar to this:

```
class UserController extends Controller {

    /** @url /user/{$slug} */
    function actionSimpleUser($slug) {
        if (!$this->viewHas('special')) {
            $this->toView('special', false);
        }
        return $this->render('user', ['slug' => $slug]);
    }

    /** @url /special-user/{$slug} */
    function actionSpecialUser($slug) {
        $this->toView('special', true);
        return $this->forwardAction('user/simpleUser', [$slug]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways you could implement this in Laravel.

You could have 2 routes that go in to 2 controller actions:

```
Route::get('/user/{slug}', 'UserController@userProfile');
Route::get('/special-user/{slug}', 'UserController@specialUserProfile');
```

And then in these controller actions, you could render the same view and set a flag to mark it as special or not:

```
public function userProfile($slug)
{
    $user = User::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    $special = false;
    return view('users.show', compact('user', 'special');
}

public function specialUserProfile($slug)
{
    $user = User::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    $special = true;
    return view('users.show', compact('user', 'special');
}
```

Then in the view file check whether the user is special or not:

```
@if($special === true)
    // special user code block
@endif
```

Comment: I was thinking about "forwarding" so I could share additional business logic between them. THe best way to share code in your approach would be having a protected method being called in the two actions, right?

Comment: Yes or you could have one route where a parameter determines whether the user is special or not. So you could have `Route::get('users/{type}/{slug}', 'UserController@userProfile');` and inside the controller the action would have 2 variables: `public function userProfile($type, $slug)` and then inside the action, you can check if type is "regular" or "admin" for example. Edit: Also yes you could abstract logic into a protected method called by both actions. This is useful on create/update methods that are very similar.